# Exibindo O Mesmo Registro Duas Vezes

Tags: php, mysql

Esse aqui é meu codigo que faz uma listagem de mesas

```
<?php 
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mesas INNER JOIN pedidos WHERE pedidos.mesa = mesas.id and conta = 0");
    if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)==true) {
       while($lnmesas = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){ 
?>
```

Eu lanço um pedido no banco de dados e ele insere ele com o nome, tamanho, valor, produzido = 0, conta = 0, e o numero da mesa ai tipo eu fiz esse inner join ai porque eu só quero que exiba a mesa que contenha um registro no banco de dados que a coluna mesa seja = ao numero da mesa na tabela mesas...

Mas ai por exemplo eu lanço dois pedidos com o numero da mesa 20
ai ele exibe pra mim duas vezes a mesa 20
se eu lançar 4 pedidos na mesa 15
ele exibe pra mim 4 vezes a mesa 15, e eu queria que ele exibisse somente um de cada.

Criei o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf9fd) para melhorar a explicação do problema.

Comment: Tentou usar o JOIN ou LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Ali também tem um erro, você precisa colocar AND mesas.conta = 0

Comment: utilize a cláusula `GROUP BY`

Comment: Use distinct.....

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo desse DISTINCT baseado no meu codigo?

Comment: @Sanção de que forma posso usar o GROUP BY para solucionar meu problema?

Comment: Neste caso ele vai repedir mesmo, pois uma mesa pode possuir mais de um pedido. Em seu exemplo, se a mesa 15 tem quatro pedidos, ele está mostrando cada pedidos dessa mesa, não está correto?  Não sei se é isso que deseja, mas [aqui tem um exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87d45/7) utilizando GROUP BY.

Comment: funcionou exatamente da forma que eu precisava, muito obrigado..

Answer (score 4):

Caro,

As querys abaixo iram retornar somente as mesas que existem na tabela pedidos. Pelo fato da tabela pedidos conter mais de uma mesma mesa é necessário o uso do `distinct` para que não ocorra o retorno de linhas duplicadas.

```
select id
  from mesas
 where id in ( select distinct mesa
                 from pedidos
                where conta = 0 );
```

**OU**

```
select distinct a.id
  from mesas a,
       pedidos b
 where a.id = b.mesa
   and b.conta = 0;
```

Abraço.